# Docker multistage build for golang create big image

Tags: docker, go, docker-compose, dockerfile, docker-multi-stage-build

I want to use the multi stage build for my gaoling project, when I build the project locally for linux/windows/Mac
I got **12.6 mb of size** , I’ve currently small gaoling CLI program.

Now I want to build it with to build from it lightwhigt docker image with the `scratch` option and build `as`

I use the following, but when I check the image, I see that the size it `366MB` , any idea what am I missing here?
It should be less then 20MB…

```
#build stage
FROM golang:alpine as builder
WORKDIR /go/src/tzf
ADD . /go/src/tzf
RUN CGO_ENABLED=0 go build -ldflags '-extldflags "-static"' -o ova tzf
RUN apk add --no-cache git



FROM golang:alpine 
RUN mkdir /build
ADD . /build/
WORKDIR /build
RUN CGO_ENABLED=0 go build -ldflags '-extldflags "-static"' -o ova tzf
FROM scratch
COPY --from=builder /build/main /app/
WORKDIR /app
CMD [“./ova -v"]
```

Comment: Debugging suggestion: if you temporarily change your final image to be `FROM busybox`, you can launch a shell in it to see what's in the image.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you build your final image, be careful to copy only the exact files you want to end up in the image.  It makes sense here to make your binary be the ENTRYPOINT of the image, since there's literally nothing else you can do with it.

I might make a two-stage pipeline like so:

```
# size of this stage doesn't matter; use the standard image
FROM golang AS builder
WORKDIR /go/src/tzf
ADD . ./
RUN CGO_ENABLED=0 go build -ldflags '-extldflags "-static"' -o /ova tzf

FROM scratch
# only copy the one file, may as well put it in /
COPY --from=builder /ova /ova
ENTRYPOINT ["/ova"]
# if you want to launch it with default options, you can
# CMD ["-v"]
```

Comment: you are amazing :) this solve the issue. thank you very much!!! . one question, is there a simple way which I can look at this container?

Comment: now the size is 11.5 MB, but since this a cli program how can I check that it working?

Comment: when i run it locally I can run command `ova -v` and it works, I see the version of the cli, how can I check it with docker to see everthing is working?

Comment: With the uncommented version of the Dockerfile, having built the image, you should be able to `docker run imagename -v` (everything after the image name gets passed as command-line arguments to the entrypoint).  Remember that the image has only the binary and not, say, a shell, so it's harder to poke around at it.

Comment: @JennyM one way i've used to do a sanity test is to add something like `RUN ["/ova", "-v"]` after the copy in the scratch image. The trick is to use the  `[]` run syntax which will not use a shell.

Answer (score 2):

You should use first a `golang:alpine` container to build the app, then an `alpine`to run the compiled app.

Something like this:

```
# builder
FROM golang:alpine AS builder
WORKDIR /go/src/tzf
ADD . /go/src/tzf
RUN CGO_ENABLED=0 go build -ldflags '-extldflags "-static"' -o ova tzf

# runner
FROM alpine
WORKDIR /app
COPY --from=builder /build/main /app/
CMD [“./ova -v"]
```

should result in a small footprint container.